# Javascript setTimeout function in window load event... not working

Tags: javascript

I've done this a month before...
But now its not working...
The code is

```
window.onload = function(){
 setTimeout(function(){
   alert("Hello");
 }, 10000);
};
```

This is written in script in head of the test.php page.
The script and other tags are correct.

I would like to call a specific function every 10 seconds. The alert just shows once only. This is problem in every browser....
After this testing i would like to check the url every 2 seconds and call an AJAX function.

Any Help??

Comment: Thanks for the setInterval function ... It worked.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's what [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) does (executes once after a specified interval). You're looking for [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval) (calls a function repeatedly, with a fixed time delay between each call to that function):

```
window.onload = function(){
   setInterval(function(){
       alert("Hello");
   }, 10000);
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval) instead.

Answer (score 3):

```
var fn = function(){alert("Hello")};
```

It is possible using setTimeout:

```
window.onload =  function(){ setTimeout( function(){ fn();window.onload() },10000) };
```

but the best solution is setInterval:

```
window.onload = function() { setInterval(fn,10000)};
```

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout is intended for one-time run. Look at setInterval function.